# How to convert the return of a function into dataframe in R?

Tags: r, function, dataframe

Consider the following code and its return:

```
my_func<- function(t=4,n=100,m=0.009){
  AA<- AB<- BB<- numeric(length = t+1)

  AA[1]<- rbinom(1,n,1-m)
  AB[1]<- BB[1]<- 0

  for(step in 1:t){
    AB[step+1]<- rbinom(1,AA[step],1-m)
    BB[step+1]<- rbinom(1,AB[step],1-m)
    AA[step+1]<- rbinom(1,BB[step],1-m)
  }
  out<- cbind(AA,AB,BB)
  return(out)
}

 my_func()

     AA AB BB
 [1,] 99  0  0
 [2,]  0 99  0
 [3,]  0  0 99
 [4,] 98  0  0
 [5,]  0 96  0
```

I'd like to be able to convert the return into a  dataframe so that I may use parts of the generated output in other functions. How would one convert this into a dataframe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On penultimate line of `my_func` change `out<- cbind(AA,AB,BB)` to `out<- cbind.data.frame(AA,AB,BB)`

Comment: First of all the line `AB[1]<- BB[1]<- 0` is not needed since you have initialized the vectors to zero. Second, instead of the two lines `out <- cbind(.)` and `return(.)` just do `data.frame(AA, AB, BB)`.

Comment: Many thanks for the help, @bouncyball

Comment: Thank you @RuriBarradas for the additional help. Additional information helps a lot when you're a rookie like me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `as.data.frame(...)` as follows:

```
my_func<- function(t=4,n=100,m=0.009){
  AA<- AB<- BB<- numeric(length = t+1)

  AA[1]<- rbinom(1,n,1-m)
  AB[1]<- BB[1]<- 0

  for(step in 1:t){
    AB[step+1]<- rbinom(1,AA[step],1-m)
    BB[step+1]<- rbinom(1,AB[step],1-m)
    AA[step+1]<- rbinom(1,BB[step],1-m)
  }
  out<- cbind(AA,AB,BB)
  return(as.data.frame(out))
}

> my_func()
  AA AB BB
1 99  0  0
2  0 99  0
3  0  0 99
4 98  0  0
5  0 96  0

> class(my_func())
[1] "data.frame"
```